# Openshift reencrypt route change destination CA certificate?

Tags: routes, certificate, openshift-3

How can I change or update the certificate used during re-encrypt route creation?
`oc update route/my-route { spec.tls.destinationcacert }` ***is immutable***.
Is there way to update the certs in re encrypt route?

Comment: found the solution.
this issue will occur when you new destination cert is not matching with cert in  your route service keystore file.
so, update your keystore file with new cert first, then update same cert by editing route.